# What environment variables will be used when calling an EXE from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

If you invoke `nmake` ( or any `exe`) on command line in Windows, Windows will search through all the `path` variables and append the directory to front of the `nmake` and execute it.

Besides `path`, is there any other environmental variable that Windows will search and append to the front of `nmake`?

Answer (score 1):

no, not that i know.

(and i do not consider PATHEXT as answer ... it just APPENDS some patterns to the thing you throw at CMD to find the right binary)

Answer (score 1):

***PATH*** is the only environment variable that contains locations that Windows will ***prepend*** to your command to find a program to run.  However, Windows does use the ***PATHEXT*** variable to determine what file extensions to ***append*** to your command to find a file to run.

The algorithm is a bit like this:

- for each entry in ***PATH***, do until a file is found:

  - file = entry + command; check for file
  - for each entry in ***PATHEXT***, do until a file is found:

    - file = file + entry; check for file
- if a file was found, run it

Answer (score 0):

No.

`PATH` is an environment variable the shell uses to resolve under-specified executable locations.  When you type `nmake`, the shell first looks in the current directory for something it can run (`nmake.exe`, `nmake.bat`, etc.) and executes it if it's found.  If not, it then looks at each directory specified in `PATH` looking for the exectuable and runs the first one it finds.

There's nothing special about `PATH` except that it's the variable the shell uses for this purpose.  There's no reason the shell would try to use any other variable for this purpose.